# Android/Java - NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
public class Excuses extends ActionBarActivity {

// openings
private String[] openings = {
                getString(R.string.opening_1),
                getString(R.string.opening_2),
                getString(R.string.opening_3),
                getString(R.string.opening_4),
                getString(R.string.opening_5),
                getString(R.string.opening_6),
                getString(R.string.opening_7),
                getString(R.string.opening_8),
                getString(R.string.opening_9),
                getString(R.string.opening_10),
                getString(R.string.opening_11),
                getString(R.string.opening_12),
                getString(R.string.opening_13),
                getString(R.string.opening_14),
                getString(R.string.opening_15),
                getString(R.string.opening_16),
                getString(R.string.opening_17)
        };
```

When ran, this error pops up:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:79)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:352)
        at com.aczylsapp.com.excusegenerator.Excuses.<init>(Excuses.java:12)
```

This line gives me the NullPointerException:

```
private String[] openings = {
```

and, I have no idea why :/
I have already looked at other posts, but they do not help me.

If someone could help me out, I would be greatful.

Comment: Are you sure that each and every one of `R.string.opening_1 ... R.string.opening_17`  is defined properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Activity` was not fully constructed, based on [`Activity` Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and you cannot access the `Resources` properly.

You must move this assignment to inside `onCreate` method. Like:

```
public class Excuses extends ActionBarActivity {

    // openings, will be initialize in onCreate method
    private String[] openings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeOpenings();

        // Your initialization code
    }

    public void initializeOpenings() {
        openings = new String[] {
            getString(R.string.opening_1),
            getString(R.string.opening_2),
            getString(R.string.opening_3),
            getString(R.string.opening_4),
            getString(R.string.opening_5),
            getString(R.string.opening_6),
            getString(R.string.opening_7),
            getString(R.string.opening_8),
            getString(R.string.opening_9),
            getString(R.string.opening_10),
            getString(R.string.opening_11),
            getString(R.string.opening_12),
            getString(R.string.opening_13),
            getString(R.string.opening_14),
            getString(R.string.opening_15),
            getString(R.string.opening_16),
            getString(R.string.opening_17)
        };
    }
}
```

## But there is a better way to do this!

Create an `String Array` in your resource, like:

```
<string-array name="openings">
    <item>@string/opening_1</item>
    <!-- Declare all your items here -->
    <item>@string/opening_17</item>
</string-array>
```

And access then with `getStringArray(int resId)`:

```
public class Excuses extends ActionBarActivity {

    // openings, will be initialize in onCreate method
    private String[] openings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeOpenings();

        // Your initialization code
    }

    public void initializeOpenings() {
        openings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.openings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer exception means that the objects you are trying to put into your array are empty or dont exist.

In your case, this likely means that `getString(R.string.opening_1)` is returning `null`.

I suspect that the issue lies with the parameter you are putting in your getString() method. If I were you, I'd take a good look at your getString() and check that `getString(R.string.opening_1)` is returning the String you want it to.

Based on the [Android Documentation for getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)), you need to make sure that the "Resource id for the string" can be found.